# Query to find ID with multiple entries based on a 2nd column with multiple values?

Tags: mysql

I have the following problem i want to select product_id from feature_values table where variant_id equals multiple values

I have this

```
SELECT product_id FROM feature_values WHERE variant_id = '162' AND variant_id = '11819'
```

**The above returns no results**

The following two queries return the product_id

```
SELECT product_id FROM feature_values WHERE variant_id = '162'
```

and this

```
SELECT product_id FROM feature_values WHERE variant_id = '11819'
```

Table example data

```
Feature ID, Product ID, Variant ID, Value
        92,        565,      11815
        69,        565,        162
        92,        566,      11819
        69,        566,        162
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `OR` rather than `AND`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these, AND is not what you are looking for, Think logically variant id can be either one or the other not both at the same time.

```
SELECT product_id FROM feature_values WHERE variant_id IN ('162', '11819')
```

OR

```
SELECT product_id FROM feature_values WHERE variant_id = '162' OR variant_id = '11819'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT product_id FROM feature_values WHERE variant_id = '162' OR variant_id = '11819'
```

or

```
SELECT product_id FROM feature_values WHERE variant_id in ('162','11819')
```